# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) whenever using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt, software-installation

I have searched all over the internet, and have found that many people have nearly the exact same problem, but differ from mine in some small way. I've tried just about every solution I've found and nothing has worked.

Whenever using `apt-get`, I get a big error, I won't post the entire output because of how big it is but it ends with

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic`

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've spent hours trying to find a solution and nothing works, many suggest methods that use `sudo apt-get autoclean` etc, but this doesn't work considering every time I use `apt-get` I get this same error.

The output of `uname -r` is `4.4.0-103-generic`

The files in my /boot directory are

```
abi-4.4.0-103-generic         lost+found
abi-4.4.0-104-generic         memtest86+.bin
config-4.4.0-103-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-4.4.0-104-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                          System.map-4.4.0-103-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic  System.map-4.4.0-104-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic   vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
```

I've had this problem for a while, but tried to ignore it as it doesn't really affect my normal browsing and use, although it has become an issue considering I can't even properly update my system now. Does anyone have any fix? I can post more of the full output if necessary

Comment: It looks like your `/boot` partition is full. Also see [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362183) and [here](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/gzip-stdout-no-space-left-on-device-update/).

Comment: try `df /boot` to see how much free space is left on it.  maybe also `df -i /boot` (but it's unlikely to have run out of inodes)

Comment: My boot directory is full, I've tried clearing old kernels before and ended up not being able to boot, even with current kernels installed. I'll clear up a few kernels and see if that helps, although I doubt it will. Edit: I deleted a kernel and then immediately when I type `sudo apt-get install` it tries to reinstall the kernel and then throws me the same error.

Comment: looks like you only have kernels vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic and 4.4.0-104.  that means you can safely remove the initrd files initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic and initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic, which will be about 25-30MB each.   BTW, how big is your /boot partition?  it must be tiny if it can't hold more than 3 or 4 kernels.  i strongly recommend that if you have a separate /boot partition, it should be at least 0.5 to 1.0GB (mine is 2GB because I want lots of room for bootable ISOs).  disks are cheap and large, you'll never notice the wasted space.  you will notice things like apt upgrades failing.

Comment: you can also delete `initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic`, which is another 25-30MB.

Answer (score 3):

> gzip: stdout: No space left on device

You need to remove to old kernel. But you should keep the latest one `4.4.0-103-generic` .

The command `sudo apt --purge autoremove` will remove the old kernels and its `linux-headers`  after executing the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then :

```
sudo apt --purge autoremove
```

Or you can remove the old kernel manually :

```
sudo apt --purge remove linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
sudo apt --purge remove linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
sudo apt --purge remove linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic
```

Also remove the `linux-headers` associated to the removed `linux-image` package.

You can use the [`purge-old-kernels`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/purge-old-kernels.1.html) after installing the `byobu` package :

```
sudo apt install byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>   This program will remove  old  kernel  and  header  packages  from  the
>    system, freeing disk space.  It will never remove the currently running
>    kernel.  By default, it will keep at least the latest  2  kernels,  but
>    the  user  can  override  that  value  using the --keep parameter.  Any
>    additional parameters will be passed directly to apt-get(8).
> ```
>
> This program requires administrative access.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> ```
> sudo purge-old-kernels --keep 3 -qy
> ```

Comment: nice tool, but wtf is a tool like that doing hidden away in a tmux/screen clone like byobu?